# Создание локальной Базы Данных для программы на Java

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

Хочу сделать Java программу для составления родословных, занятия генеалогией. И мне нужно, чтобы при создании нового проекта создавалась база данных, в которую заносились бы и потом использовались бы данные. Я предполагаю реализовать создание БД на основе SQL запросов, но не знаю как. Или возможно кто может посоветовать более удобный для данного случая метод.

Comment: Прочитайте документацию, узнаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно я вас не совсем правильно понял :) но попробуем. Для локальных приложений вы можете использовать H2 или Sqlite, т.е вам лучше всего что-то легковесное, встраиваемое. Если же Вы разрабатываете серверное решение, то я бы смотрел в сторону postgresql или MySql.

При разработке на языке Java обычно применяют ORM подход, смотрите в сторону Hibernate/JPA. При настройке hibernate используйте свойство hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto со значением create-drop тогда при старте вашего приложения схема БД будет удаляться и создаваться заново (удобно при разработке).

Так же обновлять/создавать схему БД и данные можно с помощью liquibase.
Все зависит от ваших потребностей

Comment: Я просто по большей части самоучка, по этому и немного странным мог показаться вопрос. Да, приложение будет локальным и спасибо, что рассказали про H2 и SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Если SQL то для начала установите сервер баз данных на локальную машину : MSSQL, Postgres, MySQL. Затем потренируйтесь в создании базы данных, таблиц, запросов в режиме SQL. Прочувствуйте информацию как она хранится, как добавляются данные, как извлекаются. Затем подключитесь к базе на вашем языке программирования вызовите команды, запросы получите данные, отправьте данные .... И думаю в последующем вы сможете создать вашу генеалогию начиная с самого Адама если конечно у вас есть данные.